# Spark dataframe ".as" function does not drop columns not present in matched case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am little bit confused on Spark's dataframe `.as[]` function,
in the documentation it says

> returns a new Dataset where each record has been mapped to the specified type.

but for example, if I do:

```
case class Person(id: Int, name: String) 
case class NewPerson(id: Int)
val person1 = Person(1, "a")
val df = Seq(person1).toDF()
val ds = df.as[NewPerson]
```

the `ds` dataset I get will still have the two columns `id` and `name` of the class `Person`. I would expect to have only the `id` column of the class `NewPerson`.

What did the function do here?

Comment: What do you mean by `ds I get will still have two columns`? How did you check that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `as` method only changes the view of the data, not the data itself, as explained in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#as%5BU%5D(implicitevidence$2:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BU%5D):

> Note that as[] only changes the view of the data that is passed into typed operations, such as map(), and does not eagerly project away any columns that are not present in the specified class.

So `as` does not remove columns that are not present in your case class, it just creates a view of your rows that you can use in typed operation.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Vincent Doba's answer, if you have used a case class `A` to create a value ds of type `Dataset[A]` then you can truncate it to the fields you need with the following:

`val ds_clean: Dataset[A] = ds.map(identity)`